# Magento Log folder permissions getting revoked everytime

Tags: magento-1.9, log

I am using Magento ver 1.9.1.0 and I have log settings enabled in admin panel, but when I delete the existing "log" dir and whenever I call log function like `Mage::log(print_r($anyData, true),NULL, 'dataprint.log');` and then when I go to log directory, it shows message "You don't have permissions to view content of this folder" in ubuntu 14.04.

Is this permission/ownership issue ?

Previously this issue wasn't there, also other folders and files permissions are fine but i can't access log without everytime giving command "chmod 777" to var/log directory.

Also if I do not delete "var/log" folder and it's files and just clear out it's files's contents, even then when I try to make new entry into log files(by calling log function) it doesn't allow me too.

Can somebody help me out here ?

Comment: can you do ls -l and show us the permissions settings for that folder, also do whoami to check which user you are using

Answer (score 2):

With the latest patch installed, file modes for newly created logs changed to 0640. See [SUPEE-6285 broken down](http://blog.philwinkle.com/supee-6285-broken-down/#permissions) by Phillip Jackson.

So this is intended behaviour that you can overcome by e.g. changing modes, groups, or setting up ACL.

Comment: I checked, it is due to patches indeed, I saw in Mage.php file the permissions are as per patch breakdown, can you guide me on how to override "Mage.php" file ?

Comment: No, don't touch this. Just add yourself to the webserver group as proposed by @lloiacono, keep on setting permissions after log creation or set up ACL.

Comment: Setting permissions immediately after log creation is fine, but how setting ACL is gonna help me as ACL is applied in admin only, please explain in detail.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more precise. I was referring to [filesystem ACLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list).

Answer (score 0):

So you can check the folder permissions for var doing **ls -l**. There check which user owns the folder (probably www-data), then you can check which user you are currently using doing **whoami**, and also you can check which **id -Gn** you user is in by typing groups.

Finally you can add your user to www-data (or to whatever group the user that owns var belongs) like this:

```
sudo useradd -g www-data yourUser
```

Comment: The above command tried to create a user account.  Instead I used  sudo usermod -G www-data yourUser